# Simulating HID on OSX : IOBluetooth or CoreBluetooth?

Tags: ios, macos, core-bluetooth, iobluetooth

I'm intending on doing some simple experiments sending simulated key strokes from mac to IOS and I'm trying to decide which framework to spend my effort on.

The impression I get is that CoreBluetooth is too high level for this and that IOBluetooth would be the best choice.

Is IOBluetooth the most suitable framework to use for simulating HID commands?

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoreBluetooth is for Bluetooth low energy (BLE), whereas IOBluetooth is for classic Bluetooth.
iOS devices can connect to HID devices over either transport: the BLE profile is called [HOGP: HID over GATT Profile](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/HOGP.aspx).

CoreBluetooth/BLE should be easier to work with, but you'll still need to implement the HID protocol yourself.

Note that Apple does prevent iOS applications from publishing HID over GATT but I assume that limitation is not present on OS X.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up for me. Im glad corebluetooth /BLE can be used because the API is much friendlier. I can turn my efforts toward the HID protocol side of things now.

Comment: For reference, it seems that as of Ventura, CoreBluetooth cannot be used to expose HID peripherals. The error "The specified UUID is not allowed for this operation." occurs when trying to add an HID or Device Information service to CBPeripheralManager. I have read elsewhere that IOBluetooth on macOS does not have this limitation, but I have not tested it yet.